# Can CakePHP event dispatcher return results from more than 1 handler?

Tags: events, cakephp, handler

I was just implementing an event handler in CakePHP and it worked well, but then I thought about adding 2 event handlers for the same event and realized that I could only return data from one handler. Is having more than 1 handler bad or is that just a limitation in CakePHP? The problem is in the CakeEventManager.php dispatch routine where it loops through listeners and the results just overwrite each other in $event->result.

```
public function dispatch($event) {
    ...

    foreach ($this->listeners($event->name()) as $listener) {
        ...

        if ($result !== null) {
            $event->result = $result;
        }
        continue;
    }
}
```

Is there some better way to return results? In my case I wanted to open a socket in a "before" event, send some data, the close the socket in an "after" event. Initially I thought I could save the socket in the model object that has the callback, but got the error "Using $this when not in object context" due to the way the handlers are called. I can return the socket if I just have one handler, but if there are multiple handlers then the last handler called could return something that overwrites the socket.

A quick hack would be to change it to

```
$event->result[] = $result;
```

Comments? Thanks

Comment: I think I found my own answer. According to the documentation I should directly set $event->result['somevar'] in the handler and as long as another event doesn't use the same key it will not get overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my own answer. According to the documentation I should directly set $event->result['somevar'] in the handler and as long as another event doesn't use the same key it will not get overwritten. In my case, I saved the socket and then passed it to future events like this:

```
        $event = new CakeEvent('Model.Label.beforeFormat', $this, array(
                'barcodePrinter' => $barcodePrinter,
                'labelData' => $labelData,
                'numRows' => $qty,
                'row' => $i,
                'eventData' => $eventData,
        ));
        $this->getEventManager()->dispatch($event);
        if (is_array($event->result)) {
            $eventData = array_merge($eventData, $event->result);
        }
```